# Java EE : Using quartz to send mail

Tags: jakarta-ee, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing a web application and I have to send mail the first day of every month.
My question is : Is it possible to use Quartz to do this job and how?

I read the documentation but I don't understand how the job of quartz can be start only once in a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.

Regarding sending email, this is the business logic. You could use libraries like JavaMail to accomplish this. Visit this [link for a simple example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

Regarding triggering this logic every month - The following code will schedule a trigger every month

```
trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .startNow()
    .withSchedule(monthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(5, 15, 0)) // fire on the 5th day of every month at 15:00
    .build();
```

Reference - [this link](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/MonthlyTrigger)

To initiate Quartz within a web application, we need to make configuration changes to web.xml.

Reference - [How-To: Initializing a scheduler within a servlet container](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler)

Comment: Yeah i know how can i send mail but i don't understand where in my web application i can put the quartz code